# Error running 'app': Default Activity not found while running cordova app in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, android-manifest

while launch Cordova  android application in the android studio i got below error

**Error running 'app': Default Activity not found**

but i have mentioned my default activity in the android manifest file, i refer StackOverflow questions but my bad luck no one solution is working ,**don't  ignore this as a duplicate question**

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: did you found any solution until now? I got the same issue

Comment: reinstalled android studio after that it's working fine,i think a studio was corrupted,not wrong with our code